# Is a random variable constant a.e. iff it is trivial sigma-algebra-measurable?

Tags: probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory

In the following question

[Is a random variable constant iff it is trivial sigma-algebra-measurable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1282282/is-a-random-variable-constant-iff-it-is-trivial-sigma-algebra-measurable/1282336#1282336),

whose answer I copy here it is proven that

> > **If $F=\{\emptyset, A\}$, then $f$ is $F$-measurable $\iff f$ is a constant**
>
> If $f==c$ is constant it is ALWAYS measurable (for any sigma-algebra).
> This holds as $f^{-1}[C]$ is $X$ if $c \in C$ and empty if $c \notin
> > C$. And both sets are in any sigma-algebra.
>
> On the other hand, if $f$ is $F$-measurable and non-constant, then it
> assumes at least two values $c_1$ and $c_2$. The set $f^{-1}[{c_1}]$
> must be in $F$ (by being $F$-measurable, as ${c_1}$ is a closed set)
> but this set is non-empty (as $c_1$ IS a value of $f$) and not $X$ (as
> the points $x$ where $f$ assumes the value $c_2$ are not in it). So
> this set cannot be in $F$, and so $f$ must be constant.

However in my probability lecture this property was given like this

**$F=\{\emptyset, A\}$, then $f$ is $F$-measurable $\iff f$ is an *a.e (almost everywhere)* constant,
f being a random variable**

Is this a generalization? How do I prove it? I ended up proving it without the a.e, just as in the reference question, and I don't know how to deal with the a.e to make it more general.
For instance in the converse: If $f=c$ a.e  then there should be sets $N$ with null measure for wich the function  is not equal to c, So when I take a borel set B and do the preimage $f^{-1}(B)$ what happens if N \subset B?  **this leads to the additional question of what is the preimage of a negligible set?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The almost-everywhere version is false: it's indeed the case that a function $f:X\to \Bbb R$ is constant if and only if it's $\{\emptyset,X\}$-measurable.

If you have a measure space $(X,\mathcal E,\mu)$ and a map $f:X\to \Bbb R$, it is true that $f$ is equal almost everywhere to a $\{\emptyset,X\}$-measurable function if and only if $f$ is almost everywhere constant, but it's hard to say if this was the intention of the claim, or if the statement you cite is just an error.

Comment: The context was the study of the conditional expectation of a random variable with repsect to a sub-sigma algebra. That is $\mathbb{E}[X|G]$ where G is a sub sigma algebra of F,  the measure space is $(\Omega ,F,\mathbb{P})$,  and we were analyzing the case when G was the trivial algebra

Comment: Then she gave that property to conclude that if the conditional expectation is G-measurable, then it is a constant a.e Does this change anything? If not, how do you prove the version you are giving in the second paragraph?

Comment: @mathlover Constant implies, by all means, constant almost everywhere, so this last assertion is fine. It's the other way around that fails.

Comment: The converse you mean?  but she said it was an iff. Could you give a counterexample?

Comment: @mathlover Of course I can. $\Omega$ is $\Bbb R$ with Lebesgue measure, $f=1_{\{0\}}$. It's constant almost-everywhere, but it isn't $\{\emptyset,\Bbb R\}$-measurable because $f^{-1}(-\infty,1/2]=\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: @mathlover As for my second statement, it's tautological once you have the characterization of constant functions: a function is almost everywhere equal to a function which satifies a property that's equivalent to being constant, if and only if it is almost everywhere constant.

Comment: However, here the fact is that the "almost-everywhere" we use for conditional expectations is implicitly meant to be "$G$-almost-everywhere" (as opposed to what one could think of your post, i.e. that you mean almost-everywhere with respect to some given larger $\sigma$-algebra). The fact is that the notion of $G$-almost-everywhere trivialises to "everywhere" for $G=\{\emptyset,X\}$: two functions are $\{\emptyset,X\}$-almost-everywhere equal if and only if they are equal. @mathlover

Comment: I am a bit confused with your counterexample. $\Omega$ is not $\mathbb{R}$ If I am not mistaken a random variable is a function $f: (\Omega, F,\mathbb{P}) \mapsto (\mathbb{R}, B ,m)$ where$ m$ is the Lebesgue measure. In your counterexample you are getting that the preimage is a subset of the real numbers, while in the context of random variables you should get a subset of the abstract $\Omega$

Comment: Can the measurable function you're giving be a random variable?

Comment: @mathlover Sorry, let $\Omega=[0,1]$ with same measure, or $\Omega=\Bbb R$ and the measure being $A\mapsto\frac1{\pi}\int_A \frac1{x^2+1}\,dx$, or whatever lets you see the forest despite the trees.

Comment: So, is the a.e version still mistaken even if considering the "G-almost-everywhere" meaning?

Comment: This answer is wrong without specifying the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$ on $\mathbb R$. For example, if $\mathcal F = \{\emptyset, \mathbb R\}$, then the identity function is measurable (and not constant).

Answer (score 0):

[This is a long comment]

> **$F=\{\emptyset, A\}$, then $f$ is $F$-measurable $\iff f$ is an *a.e (almost everywhere)* constant,  f being a random variable**

We have $\Rightarrow$, but *not* $\Leftarrow$, as explained in the accepted answer. This question is settled.

However, I was thinking about what I believe to be the unspoken essence of your question, based on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3932194/is-a-random-variable-constant-a-e-iff-it-is-trivial-sigma-algebra-measurable#comment8109367_3932203) comment. Here is how I'd phrase it:

> For most practical purposes, we don't distinguish between a.e. equal variables. For example, between a constant $c$ and an a.e. constant $C\stackrel{\text{a.e.}}{=}c$. However, $c$ qualifies as a candidate for $E[X]$, but $C$ does not, because it is not $F$-measurable, unless $C\equiv c$. Why do we disqualify a.e. equal random variables from conditional expectation candidates?

More generally,

> [Why not defining random variables as equivalence classes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2025058/why-not-defining-random-variables-as-equivalence-classes)

The answer to the linked question is given therein: it has something to do with stochastic processes indexed by uncountable sets.

See also:

- [Why keeping a disctinction between almost surely equal elements in probability theory?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2048078/why-keeping-a-disctinction-between-almost-surely-equal-elements-in-probability-t)
- [Are as constant but not constant random variables trivial sigma-algebra-measurable? Converse?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1290073).